# How to execute an script as daemon with nohup?

Tags: bash, scripts, services, background-process

Supose I have a script "script1.sh" and I want to execute it as a daemon with nohup and &, and make it be "waiting" for a signal. How should I do that?

Comment: Why `nohup`? you won't be able to send SIGHUP to the process after that.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's no way for a child process to become a daemon directly from an interactive login session.  The system is designed to prevent child processes from being able to "escape" being tracked as part of the login session.  You're using Ubuntu Linux.  If you _really_ want a daemon, look at systemd's "user services" for version 15.  Look at upstart's "session jobs" for prior versions.  If you just want a _background process_ then don't conflate that with being a daemon.

Answer (score 2):

In `bash`, the latest backround process' PID is stored in `$!`:

```
nohup <command> & pid=$!
```

To send a process a signal you can use `kill`:

```
kill -<signal> <pid>
```

Putting the pieces toghether, to start e.g. a background `watch -n1 echo foo` process and send it e.g. a SIGTERM signal later:

```
nohup watch -n1 echo foo & pid=$!
# ...
kill -15 $pid
```